# Mod_pagespeed thinks everything is uncacheable on https

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, mod-pagespeed

I have a pretty stock setup of mod_pagespeed on a stock CentOS6 with stock Apache 2.2. All I do is set "ModPagespeed on" in the VirtualHost. I can see the "-Mod-Pagespeed      1.13.35.2-0" http header. When using the "?PageSpeedFilters=debug" url query string I can see a lot of comments like these in the source(*):

```
<!--Uncacheable content, preventing rewriting of https://www.example.com/app/css/vendor/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css-->
```

I can fetch these files fine and there are no cache headers.

I can see it working as expected on HTTP but not HTTPS.

I have tried these directives to enable fetching over HTTP instead of HTTPS but still getting 'uncacheable content':

```
ModPagespeedDomain https://example.com
ModPagespeedDomain https://www.example.com
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain "http://fetch.example.com" "https://example.com"
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain "http://fetch.example.com" "https://www.example.com"
```

^ I have confirmed with wget I can get the files that are in the html source under fetch.example.com on the server.

Thank you,

*At the end of the file I see this debug which looks okay to me:

```
mod_pagespeed on
Filters:
ah      Add Head
cc      Combine Css
jc      Combine Javascript
gp      Convert Gif to Png
jp      Convert Jpeg to Progressive
jw      Convert Jpeg To Webp
mc      Convert Meta Tags
pj      Convert Png to Jpeg
ws      When converting images to WebP, prefer lossless conversions
db      Debug
ec      Cache Extend Css
ei      Cache Extend Images
es      Cache Extend Scripts
fc      Fallback Rewrite Css 
if      Flatten CSS Imports
hw      Flushes html
ci      Inline Css
ii      Inline Images
il      Inline @import to Link
ji      Inline Javascript
js      Jpeg Subsampling
rj      Recompress Jpeg
rp      Recompress Png
rw      Recompress Webp
ri      Resize Images
cf      Rewrite Css
jm      Rewrite External Javascript
jj      Rewrite Inline Javascript
cu      Rewrite Style Attributes With Url
cp      Strip Image Color Profiles
md      Strip Image Meta Data

Options:
EnableRewriting (e) 1
FileCacheInodeLimit (afcl) 500000
RunExperiment (fur) False
StatisticsLogging (asle) True

#NumFlushes            0
#EndDocument after     1955us
#Total Parse duration  1799us
#Total Render duration 23022us
#Total Idle duration   156us
No critical images detected.
The following filters were disabled for this request:
        SupportNoscript
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a lack of "ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable" in my live environment although I thought I read that was now the default but okay.

Additionally, I was confused in my dev environment due to self-signed ssl certificates (even though I told it to map to http) but the self-signed thing was fixed by using "ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable,allow_self_signed,allow_unknown_certificate_authority".

Now both dev and live environments are compressing/optimizing/inlining/etc as expected from mod_pagespeed.

Docs on the additional ModPagespeedFetchHttps values here:

https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/https_support#https_fetch

The relevant bits:

```
The available options are

    enable
    disable
    allow_self_signed
    allow_unknown_certificate_authority
    allow_certificate_not_yet_valid
```